# Could not find suitable NamedParameterJdbcTemplate bean

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to write an api using Spring Boot PostgreSQL. However when I try to start the application I get following error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report 
   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-07-01 11:39:49.019 ERROR 1328 --- [           main] 
  o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field template in com.employee.dao.EmployeeDAOServiceImpl required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
- 
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 
'org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate' in your configuration.
```

Here is my current code:

**DAOImpl Class**

```
@Repository
@ComponentScan("com.employee")
public class EmployeeDAOServiceImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {    
      return template.query("select * from employee", new EmployeeRowMapper());
    }

}
```

**Controller Class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employees")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/allEmployees")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    }

}
```

**ServiceImpl**

```
@Service
@ComponentScan("com.employee")
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {

        return employeeDAO.getAllEmployees();
    }

}
```

**Application class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class EmployeeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmployeeApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.employee</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-postgres</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>spring-boot-postgres</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:/schema.sql
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
```

Comment: Please help me in resolving it

Comment: Do you have something like the following dependency in your `pom.xml` file? `<dependency><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId></dependency>`

Comment: On the other hand, please include the code/exception inside the question, instead of use links with pictures for that

Comment: You only need `ComponentScan` in `EmployeeApplication`. Remove `@Service` in your `EmployeeDaoServiceImpl` (it is enough with `@Repository`) and remove the constructor (you do not need it in your example)

Comment: Where is the rest of the code/exception you initially had in attached pictures? You can use `{}` icon to include the code/exception. On the other hand, here you will see a tutorial about how to ask a question in this web https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have added the code now and did changes as suggested however still getting the same  error , any help is appreciated

Comment: Remove all `@ComponentScan` you do not need any of them. Same for `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and include in your `application.properties` or `application.yml` the Spring properties to access your database, here you have an example: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/datasource-configuration/

Comment: Removing @EnableAutoConfiguration is giving below error  
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.Following is my application.properties 

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
 If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
 If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Comment: The following link has a very similar example to your own one: https://dzone.com/articles/bounty-spring-boot-and-postgresql-database

Comment: Yes I have refered the same and done the above practise example however few changes also i have done but no luck